# Homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $(0, \infty)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to find a homeomorphism between $(0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. I would like to confirm that my answer is complete and not missing any steps. My answer:

Denote $X = (0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $Y = (0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.
Find $f: X \to Y$, s.t $f$ is a bijection, is continuous, has a continuous inverse.
Let us try $f(x) = e^{-1/x} = y$, for $x \in X; y \in Y$.

First, $f$ is a bijection on $X$.
Second, $f$ is continuous on $X$.
Third, we check if $f^{-1}$ exists. It can be solved for by applying ln on both sides of $e^{-1/x} = y$ to get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln (e^{-1/x}) = \ln (y)\\
\dfrac{-1}{x} \ln (e) = \ln (y)\\
\dfrac{-1}{x} = \ln (y)\\
\dfrac{-1}{\ln (y)} = x = f^{-1}(y)
\end{eqnarray}
I can verify that $f:(0,\infty) \to (0,1)$ and inversely, $f^{-1}: (0,1) \to (0,\infty)$, i.e the bounds of $X$ and $Y$ are correspondingly mapped.

Am I missing anything else? I ask because exercise 9.5 in [http://home.iitk.ac.in/~chavan/topology_mth304.pdf](http://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Echavan/topology_mth304.pdf) asks to prove that $e^{-x}$ is a homeomorphism from $(0,\infty) \to (0,1)$. When I try it however, the bounds are getting switched, i.e. $(0,\infty) \to (1,0)$.

1. Is my answer correct? What am I missing?
2. Where am I going wrong with $e^{-x}$? Or is it correct because there is no sense of "order" or sequence in a topological context?

- Note: I am learning on my own and am using John.M.Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds.

Thank you.

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is correct. The order doesn't play any role here.

Comment: You need to show that the inverse is continuous.

Comment: @amsmath - ok thanks.

Comment: @DonThousand - Yes, thank you. $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. So I should be done, right?

Comment: Incidentally, the hyperbolic tangent $\tanh$ is homeomorphism $(0, \infty) \to (0, 1)$ that preserves the order $<$.

Comment: There is a notion of order here: the function $f : x \mapsto e^{-1/x}$ is *order-preserving* (meaning that $a \leq b \!\implies\! f(a) \leq f(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$) while the function $g : x \mapsto e^{-x}$ is *order-reversing* (meaning that $a \leq b \!\implies\! f(b) \leq f(a)$ for all $a$ and $b$). Anyway, $f$ and $g$ are bijections $(0,\infty) \to (0,1)$.

Comment: IIRC, $f(x) = x/(1 + x)$ is a lower-tech example.

Comment: @azif00 - That makes sense. So, is there a preference for one or the other when one tries to find a homeomorphism for the purpose of showing that two spaces are topologically equivalent?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang - what is IIRC? and thank you.

Comment: @ Travis Willse - Noted; thank you!

Comment: IIRC = if it really counts ;)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh! :D Enlightened; thank you!